# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

````
@bot.command()
async def vote(reaction, ctx) :
    vote = ctx.message.content[4:].split(" / ")
    await ctx.send(ctx.channel, "[Vote] - " + vote[0])
    for i in range(1, len(vote)) :
        choose = await ctx.send(ctx.channel, "```" + vote[i] + "```")
        await ctx.add_reaction(choose, "⭕")
        await ctx.add_reaction(choose, "❌")
````

I get error :

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message'
```

The following error appears when I execute the code.

It was executed before I entered these codes.

Finally, the `add_reaction` feature will not run in the discord.

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code:

- `ctx` must be the first argument of any command. In your case, the [`discord.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) object that you expect would be `reaction` and that's why you have this error. Your function definition should be:

  ```py
  @bot.command()
  async def vote(ctx, reaction):
  ```
- In the code you gave, the `reaction` variable is useless, if you shared your entire function, you can delete it.
- The way you send messages is wrong, what you should do instead is this:

  ````
  await ctx.send(f"[Vote] - {vote[0]}")
  (...)
  msg = await ctx.send(f"```{vote[i]}```")
  ````
- The way you add reaction is also wrong. What you have to do now is this:

  ````py
  @bot.command()
  async def vote(ctx) :
      vote = ctx.message.content[4:].split(" / ")
      await ctx.send(ctx.channel, "[Vote] - " + vote[0])
      for i in range(1, len(vote)):
          msg = await ctx.send(f"```{vote[i]}```")
          await msg.add_reaction("⭕")
          await msg.add_reaction("❌")
  ````

It seems that you mix up the old discord.py (below v1.0) and the actual discord.py rewrite (after v1.0). The following link summarizes the difference between those two versions: [Migrating to v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=migrating).

Comment: The error has been resolved! Thank you for your reply.